# Inside a car with light bouncing vertically between two mirrors, now if the car starts moving will the light also move with the car?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, reference-frames, reflection

Consider two person one is travelling in a space ship and one is on the moon, now in the space ship there is a device where a light beam or photon is bouncing between two mirrors now when the space ship moves shouldnt the light beam or photon stay where it is relative to the observer on the moon meaning that space should should go ahead a the photon would not move along with the space ship

Comment: See https://physics.weber.edu/galli/RelativisticReflection.pdf

Comment: thanks got it..

Answer (score 0):

> should'nt the light beam or photon stay where it is

Light, electromagnetic wave, is a classical manifestation of the superposition of zillions of photons. Photons are elementary particles. Both move with velocity c , and cannot "stay" anyplace. c is an enormous velocity with respect to motions of moons and spaceships.

At relativistic speeds the geometry of the reflecting devise will change relative to the observer on the moon due to [length contraction.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_contraction)

Comment: So what would effect the light that it also starts moving horizontally along with the space ship when it is a bouncing vertically between mirrors

Comment: it is always new photons (classical energy light too) as it moves with velocity c always.The vertical geometry should not be affected

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcW9vDW06sc&list=PL-RmwJq2kMwn7xz05T3cEJW19_ShsRIgE&index=3  in this video at 1.42 the light ray can be seen travelling vertically and horizontally i cant understand how the light is travelling horizontally there is no medium to take the light with it but as the space ship moves so does the ray

Comment: Light does not need a medium. see the mchelson morley experiment  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment